# How to Increase size of AppBar leading property in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, stack

I'm trying to add my custom text button into AppBar leading property. However when the text gets too long then it end up in multi lines.How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you share pictorial representation of your expected output?

Answer (score 38):

Adds leadingWidth property in AppBar and SliverAppBar to customize width of leading widget. By default, the value of leadingWidth will be 56.0 to follow Material specs.

Example usage:

```
AppBar(
title: const Text('Title'),
 leading: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
 leadingWidth: 100,
)
```